# chrome.runtime.sendMessage not working on generalizing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Case 1**

I am using this snippet to send a request to my background page, and receive a message

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({details: "Command1"}, function(response) {
              console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

This works perfectly when it is called stand alone.

Here is my background page code which responds to the request :-

```
if(typeof(request.details) != "undefined"){
        console.log("Detail Array was asked for !");
        sendResponse({farewell: "Some Data here"});
        console.log("Respo 1 sent");
    }
```

As expected, on calling details : command1 from content script page, I get the expected output "Some Data here", back in my content scripts

**Case 2**

I am trying to generalize this for a number of requests, so, I did a change in my content scripts as shown :-

```
function sendMessage(toSendKey, toSendVal, funcName){
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({toSendKey: toSendVal}, function(response) {
           console.log("Response received");
           respoObt = response.farewell;
           console.log(respoObt);
           funcName(respoObt);
         });

}

function doNothing(data){
    console.log(data);
}

sendMessage("details", "Command1", doNothing);
```

Now on calling the function with appropriate parameters, I can see the two console logs ("Detail Array was asked for !", "Respo 1 sent") in my background page, confirming that the request has reached it, but, the response sent back is not able to reach to content script page.

What could be the possible culprit ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: what's the new background code? are you still looking for request.details?

Comment: @dandavis Yes, I am !

Comment: well if you are still looking for request.details, you need to popuilate that on the new message envelope you're sending, or the condition will always fail and nothing will happen in the background. post the broken code for help with the broken code.

Comment: But background code seems to be receiving the inputs. It is exactly same as in the first case

Comment: @Xan Tried that, didn't worked !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)